# "in - ing" to "when S + V"

Tags: meaning

Can I change "in gaining weight" into "when S + V" form?

> The availability of different types of food is one factor in gaining weight.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when S + V"* form? Do you mean to say *when weight gaining*?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to “when [someone] gains weight”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want *weight* to be the subject, you're turning the object into the subject, so you're talking about **passivisation**. To do that, you turn the object into the subject, to *to be*, and the past participle so "gaining weight" becomes "weight being gained" if it's you want to keep it as progressive/gerund (in the example sentence, it's a gerund). Often, even if it is progressive, it's better to lose the progressive aspect when passivising - so you may want "weight is gained". And sometimes you want it to be "weight is being gained".

So, let's look at how these fit into your sentence:

> The availability of different types of food is one factor in weight being gained.

That's the most straightforward passivisation. But you want to make it *when*. "When weight being gained" doesn't work; you need something with a non-gerund/progressive *to be*:

> The availability of different types of food is one factor when weight is gained.
>   The availability of different types of food is one factor when weight is being gained.

Those are grammatically valid, but don't make sense semantically. The original sentence is saying that the availability of different types of food is a factor that *determines* or *predicts* the gaining of weight. That's what it generally means for something to be a *factor in* something. If you want to keep the sentence as similar as possible, but turn the last bit into a *when* parameter, you have to do something like:

> The availability of different types of food is one factor in predicting when weight will be gained.

Even that's dubious, and depends on context, because the availability of food depends on more than time, and *when* suggests time. *Where* suggests more conditions than just time, so might indicate location or socioeconomic factors.

Basically, yes, grammatically you can do that, in the ways I have described, but it is unlikely to give you a good result. It will change the meaning or lead to a more complex and possibly misleading sentence.